# Понятия замка и значение слова "замкнуть"

Tags: значение-слов

Можно ли назвать замком такое врезное устройство, при котором по запирании сохраняется возможность войти (запирание носит функцию фиксации двери)? То есть врезную защелку. При поворачивании ручки входной двери (не ключа - ручки!) можно ли говорить о том, что дверь была закрыта на замок? Или только при манипуляциях с ключом? Слово "замкнуть" применимо только к устройствам замков или тождественно "запереть"?

Comment: Только к устройствам замков - одинаковый корень. Нельзя же сказать, что замкнул дверь, подперев её шкафом.

Answer (score 2):

Замок - устройство для запирания чего-либо ключом. Это словарь. То есть без ключа это уже не замок (в значении "дверной замок").

Данное слово также используется в значении фиксации, но только не двери:

- плотн. способ соединения деревянных частей между собой (бревен, брусьев) ◆ Замок угловой внакладку. ◆ Замок шпунтовый;

- то же, что уключина, приспособление для фиксации вёсел на лодке;

- приспособление для смыкания концов ожерелья, браслета, цепочки, серёг.